# DLINK DIR-685 Rev.A shows ping flood attacks from my modem ip address

Tags: wireless-router, cable-modem

DLINK DIR-685 Rev.A shows ping flood attacks from my modem ip address

This has happened with ADSL(dont remember model) and now Cable modem(Motorola SB6141).

What if anything is wrong? Is this a setting issue? What is the fix?
I am not running any kind of website or server, I am just a normal internet user(email research surfing etc.)

Comment: have you seen this? [What can I do about “ping flooding”?](http://superuser.com/questions/408537/what-can-i-do-about-ping-flooding)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. There's nothing to fix. Welcome to the Internet's background noise.