# DOS attacks using cmd and protection against them

Tags: security, ip, cmd.exe, ping, denial-of-service

After finding someones ip you can easily send pings to them to make DOS attacks. Me and my friend tried to make a defense against them and wanted to know how a low level attacker can send this DOS attacks. When one of us sent pings to the other using cmd when we were connected to the same modem(wifi) it succeed in sending pings. But when we were on different networks it failed and sent a message like "Request timed out". I assume this is a failure message but I've some questions in this matter.

I won't write the command to make DOS attacks since I don't want to encourage anyone in making those and anyone who is knowledgeable in this subject already knows how to do that.

//Assume that attacker knows the ip of the victim. Questions

Can a computer be successful enough to slow down the second computer if he sends infinite pings? If so in how much time(approximately.)(assume their computers are same.) What can be the worst result for the victim?
How can someone be successful in making DOS attacks to people who are connected into different networks from cmd? And how can I take measures against them?

Comment: Duplicate: [What can I do about "ping flooding"?](http://superuser.com/q/408537)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do about "ping flooding"?](http://superuser.com/questions/408537/what-can-i-do-about-ping-flooding)

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt isn't a very useful tool for DoSing. LOIC (Low Orbit Ion Cannon) is common among most script-kiddes and is an overall better program. You shouldn't be worried about being attacked if you don't stir up trouble online. You should be more worried about people getting your address and sending pizzas to your house.

If you must protect yourself, in the event of an attack then preventing DoS or DDoS attacks can be fairly simple.

**Step 1: Block their IP address.**

This is assuming that this is a DoS attack (coming from 1 IP address.). Use tools like Wireshark to see where this attack is coming from. Then use online tutorials on how to block IP addresses on your firewall. Block the attacker on any P2P (peer to peer) applications (like Skype) so they cannot find your IP address through them. Also, find out how to stop Skype resolvers from getting your IP. (VPNs are useful too!)

http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/How-to-protect-your-IP-from-skype-resolvers/td-p/3874291

**Step 2: Change your IP address**

It's called a 'release and renew'. You can figure out how to do through Google searching. But unplugging your modem and leaving it unplugged for a long period of time (8 - 24 hours) should work.

**Last resort**

If nothing above has helped then contact your ISP and ask for help.